# Value not binding in angular custom radio button component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, radio-button, angular-directive, angular-components

I have created a custom radio button component in angular js which will be used across my application. following is the code i wrote for the component.

**JS**

```
angular.module("customComponent")
    .component("ngRadiobutton", {
        template:        
             '<label class="ng-control-radio-button">' +
             '  <span data-ng-bind="$ctrl.label"></span>' +
             '  <input type="radio" name="{{$ctrl.group}}" data-ng-model="$ctrl.checked"/>' +
             '  <div class="ng-control-indicator-radio"></div>' +
             '</label>' +
             '',       

        bindings: {
            label: '=?',
            checked: '=',
            group: '@'
        },
        controller: function () {
            var $ctrl = this;
            console.log($ctrl.checked);  // Data is binding properly at this stage
        }
    });
```

**HTML**

```
    <div data-ng-repeat="radio in vm.radioValues">
         <ng-radiobutton label="radio.label " group="group1 " checked="radio.checked"></ng-radiobutton>
    </div>
```

**JSON**

```
    vm.radioValues = [{ label: 'Value1', checked: true },
        { label: 'Value2', checked:false }
    ];
```

The issue i am facing is that the ***true*** and ***false*** value which i am setting is not getting bind with the component. by default both the radio button is unchecked. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: label value is getting binded? @Shareer

Comment: Yes. everything else works perfect @Aparna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you try to have the Checkbox behavior for Radio button. (It is not really a binding problem)

Here is a valid version of what you can have :

```js
angular.module("customComponent", [])
    .component("ngRadiobutton", {
        template:        
             '<label class="ng-control-radio-button">' +
             '  <span data-ng-bind="$ctrl.label"></span>' +
             '  <input type="radio" name="{{$ctrl.group}}" data-ng-model="$ctrl.checked" value="{{$ctrl.label}}" />' +
             '  <div class="ng-control-indicator-radio"></div>' +
             '</label>' +
             '',       

        bindings: {
            label: '=?',
            checked: '=',
            group: '@'
        },
        controller: function () {
            var $ctrl = this;
            console.log($ctrl.checked);  // Data is binding properly at this stage
        }
    });

angular.module("customComponent").controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.group = {value: 'Value2' };
  
  $scope.radioValues = [
      { label: 'Value1' },
      { label: 'Value2' }
    ];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="customComponent">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div data-ng-repeat="radio in radioValues">
         <ng-radiobutton label="radio.label" group="group1" checked="group.value"></ng-radiobutton>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because boolean values in javascript are passed *by value*, and not *by reference*. To solve this issue, simply pass an object instead of the pure boolean value:

```
<ng-radiobutton label="radio.label " group="group1 " checked="radio"></ng-radiobutton>
```

and your component template to:

```
<input type="radio" name="{{$ctrl.group}}" data-ng-model="$ctrl.checked.checked"/>' +
```

Comment: i have changed the code like you mentioned but unfortunately i still have the issue @Luxor001

Comment: what does console.log($ctrl.checked.checked) yield?